# Centre-of-mass at a different location from the object's origin?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, origin

So I'm modelling objects where the vertices are aligned to the grid, and I snap the objects to the grid often so it is important that the origin is aligned to the grid as well. Of course when adding rigid-body simulation that becomes a problem as the origin is also the centre-of-mass, which will not necessarily be align to the grid. I need to know if it is possible to set the centre-of-mass to a distinct location from the origin in Blender.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread your question, so I removed my answer, I'm not sure if it's possible to unlink the two. Off the top of my head, if your scene is simple enough to duplicate the objects, have a layer for organizing the objects, and have the simulation on a different layer and render that layer only, and lastly copy your final locations over to the physics objects layer, but that's definitely more of a hack.

Comment: Oh, so basically what you're say is that you could have the origin set to the centre-of-mass for the physics simulation, then have an empty aligned to the grid, then parent the object to the empty meaning when the empty is snapped to the grid the object is as well. That is insanely complicated and lowers that maximum amount of useful objects Blender could handle in a scene, but it is one workaround.

Comment: Just want to add to my previous comment. Another problem with that method is that when physics simulations are run, the empty will not follow the object. I have attempted to get around this, but I am confident that there is no workaround.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I did a little more searching and found the link below. It's just someone suggesting an idea similar to yours.  https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Jzbbbc/

Comment: Take a look at this answer.  It provides a way to setup the moment if inertia and can be used to set the center of gravity. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39169/how-can-a-force-be-applied-not-to-the-center-of-a-rigid-body-object-but-to-one#42237